# When i give Mulitiple values for @GetCustomerTable i got this error

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetNews2, Line 27 Subquery
>   returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetNews2, Line 32
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetNews2, Line 36
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, , <= , >, >= or when the
>   subquery is used as an expression. Msg 512, Level 16, State 1,
>   Procedure GetNews2, Line 40 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This
>   is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or
>   when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
alter proc GetNews2
(@GetCustomerTable [dbo].[CustomerTableType] readonly,
@GetProjectTable [dbo].[ProjectTableType] readonly )
as
begin
set nocount on

CREATE table #newsTemp( NewsId      BIGINT,
                            Title       nchar(550),
                            [Description] NVARCHAR(max),
                            CreatedDate Datetimeoffset,
                            CreatedBy int,
                            IsDeleted bit,
                            CustomerId  INT,
                            Projectid   INT) 

;WITH Getnew_cte (NewsId,Title,[Description],CreatedDate,CreatedBy,IsDeleted,CustomerId,ProjectId)  
as
(
select N.NewsId,N.Title,N.[Description],N.CreatedDate,N.CreatedBy,N.IsDeleted,ct.CustomerId,pt.ProjectId  from News N
full join CustomersNews ct on N.NewsId = ct.NewsId 
full join ProjectsNews pt on N.NewsId = pt.NewsId 
)
 insert into #newsTemp
select NewsId,Title,[Description],CreatedDate,CreatedBy,IsDeleted,CustomerId,ProjectId from Getnew_cte

 if 
  ((select * from @GetCustomerTable) IS NULL and (select * from @GetProjectTable) is null)
  begin
  (select * from #newsTemp where #newsTemp.CustomerId Is nulL and #newsTemp.ProjectId is null )
  end
 if ((select * from @GetCustomerTable) is null) and ((select * from @GetProjectTable) is not null)
 begin
  (select * from #newsTemp where #newsTemp.CustomerId Is null and #newsTemp.ProjectId in (select projectId from @GetProjectTable))
  end
 if ((select *from @GetCustomerTable) is not null) and ((select * from @GetProjectTable) is null)
 begin
  (select * from #newsTemp where #newsTemp.CustomerId in (select CustomerId from @GetCustomerTable) and #newsTemp.ProjectId is null)
  end
 if ((select * from @GetCustomerTable) is not null) and ((select * from @GetProjectTable)  is not null)
 begin 
 (select * from #newsTemp where ((#newsTemp.CustomerId in (select CustomerId from @GetCustomerTable)) and (#newsTemp.ProjectId in (select projectId from @GetProjectTable))))
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

With multiple values in your type variable `@GetCustomerTable` this will not work:

```
(select * from @GetCustomerTable) IS NULL
```

You might try

```
(select count(*) from @GetCustomerTable)=0
```

But - actually - this would work only if you expect your `@GetCustomerTable` to be empty...

Another approach could be (but this depends on the content of your table type)

```
(select TOP 1 OneSpecificColumn FROM @GetCustomerTable) IS NULL
```

or

```
(select OneSpecificColumn FROM @GetCustomerTable WHERE aCritReturningOneRow) IS NULL
```

Anyway: If you want to check with `IS NULL` there must be a specific scalar value...